# How do I add a mandatory cells requirement to a macro?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm trying my luck at automating a business process and I'm running into some trouble.

I've managed to piece together the below code so far, in a nutshell all it does is saves a copy of the open worksheet to our SharePoint site upon clicking a command button. The code is probably pretty ugly but it works, and it's my first attempt.

I've created a Range called "Mandatory" and I'd like to add some code that will prevent the worksheet saving and pop up with a MessageBox asking the user to complete all the Mandatory Field if any of the cells within the Range are blank. -- *Extra credit I'd like to highlight these somehow if possible but that's a would like rather than must at this point.*

```
Sub Save_Worksheet()

ActiveSheet.Unprotect

'Variables for saving worksheet to SharePoint, establishing correct file name & extension

Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long
Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
Dim Destwb As Workbook
Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim TempFileName As String
Dim mbResult As Integer

 With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook

ActiveSheet.Copy
Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook


'Establish File Extension type
With Destwb
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then

        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else

        If Sourcewb.Name = .Name Then
            With Application
                .ScreenUpdating = True
                .EnableEvents = True
            End With
        Else
            FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
        End If
    End If
End With

'Save the new workbook and close it
TempFilePath = ("\\linktomysharepoint") & "\"
TempFileName = Range("A1").Text

'Confirm Submission
mbResult = MsgBox("This submission cannot be undone. Would you like to continue?", _
vbYesNo)

Select Case mbResult
Case vbNo
    Exit Sub
End Select

'Build .SaveAs file Name based on variables established previously
With Destwb
    .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, 
FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
    .Close savechanges:=False
End With

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ThisWorkbook.Activate

'Display successful submission message
MsgBox ("Thank you, your assessment has been successfully submitted.")

ActiveSheet.Protect

End Sub
```

I've been playing around with the following and I can't for the life of me seem to get it to work, I found it here: https://excelribbon.tips.net/T009574_Requiring_Input.html

I've set up the "Mandatory" Range it uses but I get an error at Sub ForceDataEntry() As Boolean

```
Sub ForceDataEntry() As Boolean

Dim rng As Range
Dim c As Variant
Dim rngCount As Integer
Dim CellCount As Integer

Set rng = Range("Mandatory")
rngCount = rng.Count

CellCount = 0
For Each c In rng
    If Len(c) > 0 Then
        CellCount = CellCount + 1
    End If
Next c
ForceDataEntry = False
If CellCount <> rngCount Then
    ForceDataEntry = True
End If

End Sub
```

And I've cut it together like this:

```
Sub Save_Worksheet()

ActiveSheet.Unprotect

'Variables for saving worksheet to SharePoint, establishing correct file name & extension
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long
Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
Dim Destwb As Workbook
Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim TempFileName As String
Dim mbResult As Integer

'Variables for Mandatory Requirement
Dim rng As Range
Dim c As Variant
Dim rngCount As Integer
Dim CellCount As Integer

 With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook

ActiveSheet.Copy
Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook


 Set rng = Range("Mandatory")
rngCount = rng.Count

CellCount = 0
For Each c In rng
    If Len(c) > 0 Then
        CellCount = CellCount + 1
    End If
Next c
ForceDataEntry = False
If CellCount <> rngCount Then
    ForceDataEntry = True
End If


'Establish File Extension type
With Destwb
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then

        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else

        If Sourcewb.Name = .Name Then
            With Application
                .ScreenUpdating = True
                .EnableEvents = True
            End With

            'MsgBox "Your answer is NO in the security dialog"
            'Exit Sub

        Else
            FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
        End If
    End If
End With

'Save the new workbook and close it
TempFilePath = ("\\mysharepoint") & "\"
TempFileName = Range("A1").Text

'Confirm Submission
mbResult = MsgBox("This submission cannot be undone. Would you like to continue?", _
vbYesNo)

Select Case mbResult
Case vbNo
    Exit Sub
End Select

'Build .SaveAs file Name based on variables established previously
With Destwb
    .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
    .Close savechanges:=False
End With

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ThisWorkbook.Activate

'Display successful submission message
MsgBox ("Thank you, your assessment has been successfully submitted.")

ActiveSheet.Protect

End Sub
```

And it gives me this error, apologies for the photos I've yet to workout how to print screen within this windows VM that we run on a MAC...

[Error Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8beL.jpg)

[Error Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnyBt.jpg)

Comment: You can't declare a subroutine's type (i.e. `Sub ForceDataEntry() As Boolean`), that should just be `Sub ForceDataEntry()`. If it were a `Function` and returning a value, then you could have that `As Boolean` - `Function ForceDataEntry(example As String) As Boolean`.

Comment: I believe that the link you referenced to set up the "Mandatory" Range, is using a pre-named range in the worksheet (often set-up using the Name Manager). If you would prefer to just reference the ranges through excel, you should set up the reference as `Gary's Student` suggests in his answer. However, you will have to edit your code in some places since the way it's defined will have changed.

Comment: @Mistella I don't see a comment from anyone else :(  I've made the Mandatory Range and it's working fine. I'm just not sure how to get the above working.

Comment: The errors which you attached indicate that Excel cannot locate a range called "Mandatory".  Can you explain how you set it up?

Comment: @Mistella ctrl+clicked my way through them all there's loads!

Comment: Have you double check that there's no typo's (either in the code or the name of the named-range)? Also, if the name has any spaces either before or after the rest of the letters, you'll need to include those in the string name in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Extra Credit:**

---

You can set up some conditional formatting on the Mandatory ranges which will change depending on whether the cell is blank or not.

**Version A**

This will format a cell with red fill if there is nothing inside it. (**Note:** this treats cells with only white space as non-blanks. If white-space should also count as blank, see `Version B` below.)

---

Explanation

---

Please not that since the equation refers to call `A1` (without the `$` to anchor the reference), which is the first cell in the applied range, the conditional formatting will check each cell individually for if it's blank.

If the equation were instead `=ISBLANK($A1)`, then if `A1` were blank, all cells in row 1 of the applied range would be formatted with the red fill. On the other hand, if the equation were `=ISBLANK(A2)`, then each cell would be formatted with the red fill **if the cell in the row below it** was blank. This is because the conditional formatting is evaluated as though the equation applies only to the first cell in the applied range, **then** expanded to cover the entire applied range, with the cell references shifting in the same way they would shift for an equation within a cell which you expanded by dragging.

[image: Format Equation]
[image: Format Range]

---

**Version B**

Same reasoning as in the `Explanation` section under `Version A`. The main difference is the actual equation input into the conditional formatting.

[image: secondary equation]

Comment: Thank you mistella, clearly been spending too much time on this one and forgot conditional formatting is a thing!